# Nginx error pages not working

Tags: nginx

I have the following vhost entry

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    #access_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;

    location  /media/ {
    root /home/luke/django/solentcms;
     }

    location  /admin/media/ {
    root /home/luke/virts/django1.25/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media;
     }

    location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
            root    /home/luke/django/solentcms/404;
            allow   all;
     }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
            root    /home/luke/django/solentcms/404;
            allow   all;
     }

}
```

However, 404's and 50x errors are still be re-directed to the horrible nginx default pages.Any ideas as to why? This syntax works on one of my other servers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are the errors coming from your backend?  You may need to add [proxy_intercept_errors](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) on; alongside your proxy_pass.

Comment: If you're using fastcgi, the setting is `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`

Comment: Thanks, that help solve my error pages not showing too.