# How to replace Nginx default error 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" page with Play! Framework backend.

Tags: nginx, playframework

I have a website using Play! framework with multiple domains proxying to the backend, example.com and example.ca.

I have all http requests on port 80 being rewritten to https on port 443. This is all working as expected.

But when I type into the address bar http://example.com:443, I'm served nginx's default error page, which says

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx
```

I'd like to serve my own error page for this, but I just can't seem to get it working. Here's a snipped of my configuration.

```
upstream my-backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen                  443;
  ssl                     on;

  ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
  keepalive_timeout       70;
  server_name             example.com;
  add_header              Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000; #six months


  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://my-backend;
  }

  error_page 400 502 error.html;
  location = /error.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }



}
```

It works when my Play! application is shut down, but when it's running it always serves up the default nginx page.

I've tried adding the error page configuration to another server block  like this

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl off;
  server_name example.com;

  error_page [..]

}
```

But that fails with the browser complaining about the certificate being wrong.

I'd really ultimately like to be able to catch and handle any errors which aren't handled by my Play! application with a custom page, or pages. I'd also like this solution to work if the user manually enters the site's IP into the address bar instead of the server name.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Nginx error pages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505678/nginx-error-pages-not-working): `"You may need to add proxy_intercept_errors on; alongside your proxy_pass.."`.  See also [nginx: error_page directive is silently ignored](https://serverfault.com/questions/326877/nginx-error-page-directive-is-silently-ignored)

Comment: I saw those pages as well. Unfortunately the proxy_intercept_errors on isn't working for me, and the second link doesn't resolve my particular case since I'm not explicitly throwing the error 400 page. It's being thrown by nginx as a default response somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610382/4023897.

In my particular case, where I want to serve a static error page under these circumstances, my configuration is as follows

```
server {
  listen                  443;
  ssl                     on;  

  ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
  keepalive_timeout       70;
  server_name             example.com;
  add_header              Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000; #six months


  location = /error.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    autoindex off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://my-backend;
  }

  # If they come here using HTTP, bounce them to the correct scheme
  error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port/error.html;


}
```